# Optional/Custom claim for OAuth app in Azure AD

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, claims, azure-app-registration

Can I add the user.officelocation claim for OAuth registered app in Azure AD? If I add it in its service principal in Enterprise Apps ? Will it work ? Do I get office location of users (synced users) in Access token? Or i need to configure something else (office location field is blank in user properties)in user' profile? My app has user.read.all scope granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Yes, you can use Azure AD access token to get office location of users.**

In the **Azure AD application** and updated the manifest:

[image]

In the **Enterprise application** added claim like below:

[image]

Granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated the **access token** and the office location claim displayed successfully:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=api://xxx/claims.read&state=12345&nonce=12345
```

[image]

> **Note** that: If the user doesn't have the office location updated then the claim will not be returned in the access token.

[image]

Make sure that the **office location attribute is sync'd or update it in user properties**:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Users -> Edit properties*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where I can find the claims.read permission in delegated permissions. Under which option i will find claims.read permission? is it testruk?

Comment: Go to Azure Portal -> Select your app -> Expose an API and scope like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/tPlEUwS.png) and the In API permissions blade -> Add a permissions -> Select APIs my organization uses and search your app like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/2SBZqQG.png) -> Select Delegated permissions and [**add**](https://i.imgur.com/ymdNXPS.png) -> Grant Admin Consent to the API permissions like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/cEf7Tkc.png).