# Implement Azure AD multi tenancy for a Blazor WASM App calling a secure web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I have successfully implemented Azure AD authentication in Blazor WASM, but now i need to modify the architecture to support any user from any AD. I have tweaked my existing code to allow a service principal be created in the user AD after sign in , but it seems i am missing something and i get an error after sign in.

I tried to follow this article
https://github.com/mrpmorris/WalkThrough-AzureActiveDirectoryMultiTenant,

but it did not help. I am guessing his approach did not consider the setup where the client calls a secure web api after login.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Azure AD Multitenant application** like below:

[image]

Expose an API:

[image]

Add and grant **admin consent** to the API permissions:

[image]

To authenticate any Azure AD users, make sure to use **`organizations`** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/access_as_user
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://ClientID/access_as_user
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

By using the above access token, you can call the web Api. Decode the access token and check the scopes:

[image]

By using the above generated access token, you can call the web Api successfully.

The [GitHub Blog](https://github.com/mrpmorris/WalkThrough-AzureActiveDirectoryMultiTenant) by *mrpmorris* is correct and make sure to use **`organizations`** endpoint in `appsettings.json`:

```cs
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "TenantId": "organizations",
  "ClientId": "ClientID}",
  "Scopes": "api://ClientID}/access_as_user"
}
```

**Reference:**

[GitHub - waelkdouh/BlazorWebAssemblyAADImplicitGrantFlow](https://github.com/waelkdouh/BlazorWebAssemblyAADImplicitGrantFlow) by Wael Kdouh

Comment: Can you include more details what error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you Sir for this detailed response. I already have an app registration in AD for the client part of WASM identical to what you described above, and another for the WebAPI.  From your example , you seem to be calling the Web API directly with the token, However in my project setup , the client uses MSAL to authenticates and then calls the protected web api. The error i get in my code suggests , a service principal is created for the Client part but not the webapi part in the external user's AD.

Comment: Did you create both application as "MultiTenant"?

Comment: Yes i created both as Multi Tenant.

Comment: Screen shots of exactly what Sir?

Comment: Of the error and code where the error is occurring

Comment: To resolve the error add the clientapp as known application in webapi like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/Boripmf.png)

Comment: Hi, You solution did work for me sir, but at the moment i am not able to get claims. Will review my code again if i am missing something, then i can make the question as resolved.

Comment: To get the claims in the access token pass scope as `api://***/scopename`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127970/optional-custom-claim-for-oauth-app-in-azure-ad#77131947