Custom Attributes in Azure AD
I have one SAML app integrated with azure AD. As per app requirements, they need additional attributes in SAML response from Azure. So we need to add additional attribute so that we can send them in claims. How to add a custom attribute and use it in my enterprise app.
eg. lang=en how can add this attribute in AAD and add it to my SAML app attributes and claims so that AAD can send this in SAML response.

Do you want to get the claims in AAD token?

You can add the claim like this

Yes @Rukmini I want the custom claims in AAD SAML token. The link you shared is not opening up.

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127970/optional-custom-claim-for-oauth-app-in-azure-ad

I want to add custom claim for SAML app only. The claim that I want in SAML response is not present in AAD attributes for any user. I need to create it from Custom Attribute settings page of AAD. How can I do that?

I created a Microsoft Entra SAML application:

To add custom attributes, check the below:
Create a policy by passing the custom attribute name and assign it to the Service Principal:
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/lang","JwtClaimType":"lang"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "lang" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy  -RefObjectId 'PolicyID' -Id 'ServicePrincipalObjID'


Now assign the policy to the user:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
"extensionAttribute1": "en"
}
}


Otherwise, you can create a new directory extension, associating them to existing user and set value like below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjID/extensionProperties
Content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "lang",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}


Now assign the attribute to the user and set the value:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn>
Content-type: application/json

{
  "extension_xxx_lang": "en"
}


In the Microsoft Entra ID application, configure the token configuration:
Token configuration -> Add optional claim -> SAML

The SAML claims will be emitted as http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/**extn
Reference:
How to add custom user attribute to use in Azure SAML SSO? - Microsoft Q&A by Siva-kumar-selvaraj

Thank you for this, but how do I use the Custom Attribute option available in AAD to create the claims.

Refer this blog https://blog.netwrix.com/2022/02/10/what-are-azure-ad-custom-security-attributes/
